# Check if a proxy can connect to a website?

Tags: java, proxy

basically I'm building a Proxy Checker to check if it can connect to a specific website. My problem is that when the proxy doesn't work it takes huge amounts of time to cancel that try and move to the next.

I've tried the "setConnectTimeout();" parameter but it doesn't seem to work properly.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
    try {
        executeLoop();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProxyCheckerGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}//GEN-LAST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed

private void executeLoop() throws Exception{

    String getProxies[] = jTextAreaProxy.getText().split("\n");
    String proxyIP;
    int proxyPORT;
    System.out.println("QuantityOfLines:" + getProxies.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < getProxies.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("Line: " + i);
        String proxy[] = getProxies[i].split(":");
        if (proxy.length == 2 & proxy[0].trim().length() > 0 && proxy[1].trim().length() > 0) {
            proxyIP = proxy[0];
            proxyPORT = Integer.parseInt(proxy[1]);

            try {
                testProxy(proxyIP, proxyPORT);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ProxyCheckerGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

}

private void testProxy(String proxyIP, int proxyPORT) throws Exception {

    String url = "https://www.google.pt";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyIP, proxyPORT));
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection(proxy);
    //con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    //con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    con.connect();
    con.setConnectTimeout(3000);

    int response = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nResponse:" + response);

    if (response == 200) {
        System.out.println("Working : " + proxyIP + ":" + proxyPORT);
        jTextAreaWorking.append(proxyIP + ":" + proxyPORT + "\n");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Working : " + proxyIP + ":" + proxyPORT);
    }
    con.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: That's a success. The proxy connected correctly to the target, but the target wasn't an HTTPS server, so you got an SSLException. This failure did not take a long time. What is your question?

Comment: @EJP oh, didn't know that, thanks. But the main problem is still the time that it takes to timeout when the proxy doesn't work.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this? Is it also possible to add several threads to make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck setting readtimeout as well

```
con.setReadTimeout(3000)
```

Sometimes the server will happily accept the connection but it just doesn't respond.

With the Exception it depends if it's a fatal exception or you can carry on after it. Here it looks like the Exception isn't Fatal just something not working from which you can recover and try something else. So yes, handle your exceptions gracefully.

Comment: The time to timeout has decreased and it's working better, but it still takes longer than what is expected. Thanks.